# R shiny updateCheckboxGroupInput does not work as expected

Tags: r, shiny

I wonder why all of my check boxes are not checked with this code ?

I have 1 checkboxGroupInput named "county" with 3 check boxes and another one
named "dynamic" with 33 check boxes. And I wonder why, when I check two or three check boxes of the "county" checkboxGroupInput, the dependent check boxes in the "dynamic" checkboxGroupInput are not checked. It works well only if one box is checked.

Thank you very much for helping.

This is the Server.R :

```
observeEvent(input$dynamic_county, {
if(is.element((input$dynamic_county),("South")))
{updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, inputId = "dynamic", selected = 
list("02","03","05","06","09","13","16","17","18","21","28","29",
"32"))}})

observeEvent(input$dynamic_county, {
if(is.element((input$dynamic_county),("North")))
{updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, inputId = "dynamic", selected = 
list("01","04","07","08","10","11","12","19","22","23","24","25","26",
"27","30","31","33"))}})

observeEvent(input$dynamic_county, {
if(is.element((input$dynamic_county),("East")))
{updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, inputId = "dynamic", selected = 
list("14","15","20"))}})
```

Thank you again.

@ Warmoverflow, thank you for suggesting but it doesn't work, I tried this :

```
observeEvent(input$dynamic_county, {
if(is.element((input$dynamic_county),("South")))
{updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, inputId = "dynamic", selected = 
list("02","03","05","06","09","13","16",
"17","18","21","27","28","29","32"))}

if(is.element((input$dynamic_county),("North")))
{updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, inputId = "dynamic", selected = 
list("01","04","07","08","10","11","12","19",
"22","23","24","25","26","27","30","31","33"))}

if(is.element((input$dynamic_county),("East")))
{updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, inputId = "dynamic", selected = 
list("14","15","20"))}
   })
```

And I tried that too :

```
observeEvent(input$dynamic_county, {
ifelse((is.element((input$dynamic_county),
("South"))),updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, inputId = "dynamic", 
selected = list("02","03","05","06","09","13","16",
"17","18","21","27","28","29","32")),


ifelse((is.element((input$dynamic_county),
("North"))),updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, inputId = "dynamic", 
selected = list("01","04","07","08","10","11","12","19",
"22","23","24","25","26","27","30","31","33")),

 ifelse((is.element((input$dynamic_county),
("East"))),updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, inputId = "dynamic", 
selected = list("14","15","20")),
updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, inputId = "dynamic",selected = 
NULL))))})
```

If I check 2 or the 3 check boxes, only one of them is executed.

Would you have an idea about the origin of the problem please ?

Thank you very much again.

EDIT :

I have understood that dynamic_choices is for labeling, so I have included my final labels but it doesn't work. I'm so disappointed to realize that I have not understood. Here is what I've done :

```
library(shiny)
library(stringr)

dynamic_choices = c("01. Bélep", "02. Boulouparis", "03. Bourail",
                    "04. Canala", "05. Dumbéa", "06. Farino",
                    "07. Hienghène", "08. Houaïlou", "09. Ile des Pins", 
                    "10. Kaala Gomen", "11. Koné", "12. Koumac",
                    "13. La Foa", "14. Lifou", "15. Maré",
                    "16. Moindou", "17. Mont Dore", "18. Nouméa",
                    "19. Ouégoa", "20. Ouvéa", "21. Païta",
                    "22. Poindimié", "23. Ponérihouen", "24. Pouébo",
                    "25. Pouembout", "26. Poum", "27. Poya",
                    "28. Sarraméa", "29. Thio", "30. Touho", "31. Voh",
                    "32. Yaté", "33. Kouaoua")

selection = list("Province Nord"=c("01. Bélep", "04. Canala",
                "07. Hienghène", "08. Houaïlou", "10. Kaala Gomen",
                "11. Koné", "12. Koumac", "19. Ouégoa", "22. Poindimié",
                "23. Ponérihouen", "24. Pouébo", "25. Pouembout",
                "26. Poum", "27. Poya", "30. Touho", "31. Voh",
                "33. Kouaoua"),
                  "Province Sud"=c("02. Boulouparis", "03. Bourail",
                "05. Dumbéa", "06. Farino", "09. Ile des Pins",
                "13. La Foa", "16. Moindou", "17. Mont Dore", 
                "18. Nouméa", "21. Païta", "28. Sarraméa",
                "29. Thio", "32. Yaté"),
                   "Province des Iles Loyauté"=c("14. Lifou",
                "15. Maré","20. Ouvéa"))

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

   titlePanel("Update CheckboxGroupInput"),

   sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      checkboxGroupInput("dynamic_provinces", "Provinces", c("Province 
                    Nord", "Province Sud", "Province des Iles Loyauté")),
      checkboxGroupInput("dynamic", "Communes", dynamic_choices)
    ),

    mainPanel(
   )
 )
))
```

And the Server.R code :

```
server <- shinyServer(function(session, input, output) {

  observeEvent(input$dynamic_provinces, {
     selected = c()

    for (s in input$dynamic_provinces) {
      selected = c(selected, selection[[s]])
    }
       if (is.null(selected)) {
      selected = character(0)
    }
     updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "dynamic", selected = selected)
   }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)

})
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Instead of having three `observeEvent`, you should have only one and put all if statements inside it.

Comment: Main issue is that when you check multiple boxes in the first group, you need to combine all corresponding options in the second checkboxgroup together. See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example. For example, when you select both "South" and "North", you need to select corresponding boxes for both. Code in your question only selects the boxes corresponding to one of them, thus the issue.

You also need to set `ignoreNULL` to `FALSE` for `observeEvent`, otherwise it won't get the event when you clear all boxes.

```
library(shiny)
library(stringr)

dynamic_choices = c(1:33)
dynamic_choices = str_pad(as.character(dynamic_choices), 2, side="left", pad="0")
selection = list("South"=c("02","03","05","06","09","13","16","17","18","21","28","29","32"),
                 "North"=c("01","04","07","08","10","11","12","19","22","23","24","25","26","27","30","31","33"),
                 "East"=c("14","15","20"))

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

   titlePanel("Update CheckboxGroupInput"),

   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        checkboxGroupInput("county", "County", c("South", "North", "East")),
        checkboxGroupInput("dynamic", "Dynamic", dynamic_choices)
      ),

      mainPanel(
      )
   )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(session, input, output) {

  observeEvent(input$county, {
    selected = c()

    for (s in input$county) {
      selected = c(selected, selection[[s]])
    }
    # This is needed due to a bug in Shiny, see https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/831
    if (is.null(selected)) {
      selected = character(0)
    }
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "dynamic", selected = selected)
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)

})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you very very much for helping Warmoverflow. Unfortunately, when I copy your answer to my R-Studio, nothing happens when I check one or more "county" boxes. I don't know why.

Comment: What versions of R and Shiny are you using? Also try restart RStudio or computer. I've checked the code on two computers and both work.

Comment: You were right Warmoverflow, I have restarted R-Studio and everything's ok. Thank you very very much for your code, it's perfect.I better understand how it works now. And thank you for answering my others threads too. Have a very good day.

Comment: Just one more question : why I have to create the objects "dynamic_choices" ans "selection" in the console first ? If I don't do that, there's an error because R doesn't find these objects ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is strange because R is supposed to create these objects (or in general, R/Shiny should run any code outside ui/server first). It may be related to the version of R or shiny, but difficult to tell.

Comment: The names in `dynamic_choices` need to be the same as the ones in `selection`. Once you change that, it should work.

Comment: Warmoverflow, I have done what you said but unfortunately it doesn't work, I'm so disappointed. I'm sorry to bother you, but could you tell me what is the problem ? Please see my edited code above. Thank you so much.

Comment: You need to move `selection=...` to `server.R` (as the variable is used in the server code). Also in `checkboxGroupInput`, `Province Nord` should be on one line in `ui.R` (right now there is a new line in the middle). Once you have done this, it should work (I've tested).

Comment: Super great ! Thanks a lot Warmoverflow, you're the best. Thank you again, have a great day.